# Ceiling fan does not stop

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I replaced the pull chain unit because  ceiling fan did not stop.  I have replaced the pull chain unit.  The fan will change speeds, but it won't turn off.

Comment: maybe you miswired it .... what was the original problem? (detailed description please)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A wiring diagram would really help us help you.

Comment: Can you post photos of how things are wired?